# ¿Cómo validar string con regex que sea alfanumerico y que pueda contener "-" y "_"?

Tags: regex, preg-match

Busco validar que un `string` cumpla con este formato:

- Que contenga letras y numeros
- Que la cadena pueda o no contener los caracteres `-` (guión medio) y `_` (guión bajo)

Realicé varias pruebas, agregando y quitando más parámetros a un `regex` que realicé, pero no funciona como lo quiero.

> Mi regex: `[\w_-]+`

Funciona parcialmente, ya que indica que contenga `alfanumericos` y `-` `_`, pero al ingresar una cadena así: `ho-la._23`, omite `._23` ya que encuentra el caracter `.` y permite continuar al encontrar `ho-la` ya que eso sí cumple con la validación.
Lo que busco es que al ingresar esa cadena `ho-la._23` o alguna otra cadena que contenga otro caracter que no sea `alfanumérico` o `_` `-`, no permita hacer match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Casi lo logras, lo puedes hacer con el siguiente `regex`:

```
^[\w-]+$
```

`\w` es equivalente a `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` que abarca todas las letras, los números del 0 al 9 y el guión bajo.

`^` es para indicar el inicio de línea y `$` para indicar el final de línea.

Probando con los siguientes `string`

```
ho-la._23
hola-23
ho-la_23
```

El primero no hace "match" pero el segundo y el tercero sí.

Hay una página que te puedo recomendar [`regex101`](https://regex101.com/), que te permite probar `regex` y a la derecha te indica lo que hace cada parte.